# Extract all rows with the same value in c2 column if at least in one row we have required value in column c1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Sorry for the title, I'll do my best to explain it here

We have a table like the following:

```
 c1 | c2 |c3
____________
111 | 11 | 2
123 | 11 | 3
111 | 44 | 4
156 | 88 | 7
111 | 44 | 8
444 | 44 | 1
123 | 11 | 4
123 | 55 | 4
```

So firstly I want to check c3 and find out whether we have a row with the value = 2 in c3 column

> 'Where c3 = 2'

this part is easy

After that we take the value of c1 (from the row that we get in previous step) - it will be 111 (as in this row we have 2 in c3)

And now is the difficult part where we want to get all the rows where if c2 value at least once had 111 value in c1 we'll take all the rows with that value in c2

For example, in the first row, we have 111 in c1, we take the value from c2 and look for all the rows from  the table where c2 value = 11 (even though c1 value won't be 111 anymore)

Those the rows I want to get in the end:

```
 c1 | c2 |c3
____________
111 | 11 | 2
123 | 11 | 3
111 | 44 | 4
111 | 44 | 8
444 | 44 | 1
123 | 11 | 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . one way translates your requirements almost directly into `in` conditions:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.c2 in (select t2.c2
               from t t2
               where t2.c1 in (select t3.c1 from t t3 where t3.c3 = 2)
              );
```